# is there a way to count the items in a page using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

the page that i'm trying to automate is my college website which has all the information about attendance of each subject, the number of subjects vary with the students with different academic years

so i need a way to count automatically count the number of subjects

```
so subject 1 Xpath - //*[@id="MainContent_GridView4"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
   subject 2 Xpath - //*[@id="MainContent_GridView4"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]
```

in xpath pattern 'tr[2] ranges from 2-10 for one student of course(Mech) and 2-9 for other student (cse )

```
temp = '//*[@id="MainContent_GridView4"]/tbody/tr['
for x in range(2,10):
       sub1 =temp + str(x) + ']/td[1]'
       k = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,sub1)
```

the above code i mentioned only works for the Cse students and when used with mech students page it seems to miss out a subject in the final list 
so if there's a way to count the number of subjects i can use that count in my loop

Answer (score 0):

You can try using find_elements in place of find_element. In case if there is no element found using the provided xpath, it will return an empty list. So, you can build a logic around it for further automation. For e.g. if size of list > 0, do something, else, do something else.